What difference does the USB-C connector make what orientation the cable connected to it is now?
I read a document from FTDI about USB Power Delivery where it is written that the connector (USB Plug) can determine the orientation of the cable by the CC pins, but I can’t find any information about why this is necessary?
https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/TN_185_What_is_USB_Power_Delivery.pdf
Page 6.

In paragraph 3.4 it is written about this, and why it is needed, because it is symmetrical?

It is necessary in some cases and in some cases it isn't.
The plugs and receptacles are symmetrical, but the signals on the connector are not and must be swapped to route correct signals to correct pins that are actually present on both ends.
For example, if you plug a cable into a USB2 device, it does not matter a bit in which orientation it is, because USB2 can be made symmetrical.
If you plug a cable into a USB3 device, the device must know in which orientation it is plugged in to use the correct wire pairs for USB3 SSTX and SSRX.
There are four high speed lanes, and standard USB3 uses only two of them. Depending on which way you plug it in, it uses TX1/RX1 pins on the connector, or TX2/RX2 pins on the connector.
If you plug a cable into a DP Alt Mode adapter to get picture between laptop and monitor, not only the order of the four high speed lanes must be known, and the low speed AUX channel must swap polarity as well.
The cables are not symmetrical either. There is only one CC wire between the plugs, which also means between the two devices, so it can be on CC1 or CC2 pin of the connector.
The other wire is used for powering the cable electronics, if it has active electronics, such as e-mark chip or buffer ICs for the data.
So a device with a receptacle must know which way the plug is in, to use the correct USB3 pins.
Non-compliant cheap devices may exclude support for swapping the pinout, so these Type-C devices work only when plugged in using the only one plug orientation that the hardware is wired to.
